# Binary Tree inorder traversal display wrong

Tags: c++, binary-tree, inorder

The display for my binary tree in-order traversal is wrong. I cant figure out what I'm doing wrong. The output is showing up at 1-15 when the height is 4 (including level 0 as 1) instead of showing up as :  8 4 9 2 10 5 11 1 12 6 13 3 14 7 15.

**main:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "math.h"
#include "bintree.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    binary_tree bin;
    int tmp, num, height;

        cout << "Please enter a height that you wish to see: " ;
        cin >> height;
        cout << endl << endl;

        bin.insert(num, height);

        cout << "The In-Order Traversal is: " ;
        bin.displayinorder();
        cout << endl << endl;



    system("Pause");
    return 0;
}

void binary_tree::insert(int num, int height)
{
  num = pow(2, height);

  for(int i = 1; i < num; i++)
  {
     node* t = new node;
     node* parent;
     t-> data = i;
     t-> left = NULL;
     t-> right = NULL;
     parent = NULL;

     if(isEmpty()) root = t;
     else
     {
         node* curr;
         curr = root;

         while(curr)
         {
             parent = curr;
             if(t->data > curr->data) curr = curr->right;
             else curr = curr->left;
         }

         if(t->data < parent->data)
            parent->left = t;
         else
            parent->right = t;
      }
   }
}


void binary_tree::displayinorder()
{
  inorder(root);
}

void binary_tree::inorder(node* p)
{
    if(p)
    {
        inorder(p -> left);
        cout<< " " << p->data <<" ";
        inorder(p -> right);
    }
}

void binary_tree::displaypreorder()
{
    preorder(root);
}

void binary_tree::preorder(node* p)
{
    if(p != NULL)
    {
        cout<<" "<< p -> data <<" ";
        preorder(p -> left);
        preorder(p -> right);
    }
    else return;
}
```

**header:**

```
#ifndef BINTREE_H
#define BINTREE_H
#include <cstdlib>  // Provides NULL and size_t

   class binary_tree
   {
      private:
       struct node
       {
          node* left;
           node* right;
           int data;
       };
      node* root;

    public:
        binary_tree()
        {
           root = NULL;
        }

        bool isEmpty() const 
        { 
             return root==NULL; 
        }

        void displayinorder();
        void inorder(node*);

        void displaypreorder();
        void preorder(node*);

        void insert(int, int);
};

#endif
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you are unclear what *in-order* means.  1 .. 15 is the expected output for in-order traversal of a binary search tree containing the values 1 .. 15.  The sequence you gave sounds like *pre-order* on a *balanced* binary search tree.

In other words, your traversal code is correct for in-order traversal.

That said, your tree *generation* code does not produce a balanced tree.  An in-order traversal won't expose that, but a pre-order or post-order traversal will.  Because you insert all of the values in increasing sequential order, you will get a tree made entirely of right children.  Add some `cout` statements to your traversal to see what I mean.

Comment: I see what you're saying about how my tree isn't balanced. Do you happen to have any tips for how I could possibly make it balanced?

Comment: @user24879 to the left of each question you will see a number and if its your question a check mark - if you like an answer it is polite to vote it up by clicking the triangle above the number and/or clicking the check mark if you believe your question was answered

Comment: @user24879:  If you want a balanced binary tree that isn't self balancing, or that you haven't done any balancing on yourself after construction, then you have to insert the nodes in the correct order.  If memory serves, for a numeric sequence 1 .. (2^n - 1), you can insert them in "bit-reversed" order.  I just tried pencil and paper for 1 .. 7 and it works.